# What is proper way to show data like app store app(Collection view inside table View)

Tags: ios

There are lots of stack-overflow thread and community articles but i just want to know which one is better to show data like App store App(Vertical scrolling of apps and sometimes horizontal scrolling inside vertical scrolling). So far i understand below might be possible solution.

**Solution 1:**
Collection View inside tableView. So that products can be scrolled horizontally inside tableView cell.

**Solution 2:**
Number of collection View inside a scrollView stacked one after another if categories are specific.

Is there any better solution to make such type of scenario?. Your opinions will be highly appreciated. Thanks

Comment: first solution is better .

Comment: Just implemented Solution 1 in a project and works flawlessly, go for it.

Comment: Thanks. Just to make sure i am in the right path. :)

Answer (score 0):

A general suggestion based on my usage, create a `tableview` and inside it's `tableviewcell` create a `collectionview`. You may use `staggered layout` for a better user interface. That is what I have been doing, you will build it much easier. [image: This is what I achieved using tableview and collectionview combined!]
Rest depends on your usage and requirement.